# How to read and write video with audio in Python Foundry Nuke?

Tags: python, audio, video, merge, nuke

I need to merge 2 videos in Python Nuke but also I want to merge their audio channels. However Nuke reads and writes only their video with no audio at all after running the code below:

```
import nuke

content = nuke.createNode("Read")
content["file"].fromUserText("/content.mp4")

bg = nuke.createNode("Read")
bg["file"].fromUserText("/bg.mov")

merged = nuke.nodes.Merge(inputs=[bg, content])

output = nuke.nodes.Write(file="/output.mov", inputs=[merged])

nuke.render(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Foundry NUKE isn't a video editor, it's a compositing package. So, if you need to merge an audio component with a video component, use `Audio File` option having a corresponding path (you can read in the same `.mov` file or choose a separate audio file).

[image]

Here's how your code should look (I used `.mov` file with Apple ProRes 4x4 codec):

```
import nuke

nuke.nodes.Read(file="/Users/swift/Desktop/TESTED.mov", last=1800)

output = nuke.nodes.Write(file="/Users/swift/Desktop/nuke1920.mov", 
                          file_type="mov", 
                          mov64_audiofile="/Users/swift/Desktop/TESTED.mov")

nuke.render(output)
```

Output pane of Script Editor presents no errors:

[image]

Alternatively, if you need to work with audio tools, use NUKE Studio.

P.S.

1. Take into consideration that Non-Commercial NUKE version supports output resolution not greater than 1920x1080. And Non-Commercial NUKE doesn't support `mp4` codec, and a processing of more than 10 nodes for Python scripting.
2. And one more thing – you're trying to render 2 videos but you're outputting only 3 channels – RGB. Make sure you have an appropriate channel set for A and B streams! I don't know what you're trying to accomplish but you may use a `Copy` node instead of `Merge` node to render 2 sets of RGBs.

Comment: After adding these knobs to the Write node I've got: RuntimeError: Write1: unsupported codec

Comment: Unsupported codec is `mp4`. Convert all your clips into `.mov` container with ProRes codecs.

Comment: Also with `mov`

Comment: `.mp4` codec inside H.264 is the same as inside `.mov` container.

Comment: Use `Apple ProRes` codecs for video. And `OpenEXR` is a great choice for sequences.

Comment: @shpindler, I've updated my answer. Please read P.S. part.

Comment: I see, I use commercial version with Python interpreter in my Django app.

Comment: Trying to understand problem with codecs to implement your solution.

Comment: NUKE is a professional tool. It shines when you load Pro-format image sequences (16 or 32 bit) or video with Pro-codecs (10 or 12 bit). I suppose NUKE engineers allow to read `.mp4` only for testing reasons.

Comment: So, all you need to do is to convert your `.mp4` (using Final Cut Pro X, or DaVinci Resolve, or Apple Compressor, or Apple Motion) into Apple ProRes 422 video (QuickTime `.mov`).

Comment: `.mp4` files is OMG!!!!-video with 4:2:0 compression which NUKE hates.

Comment: I tried with only `mov` files and still have unsupported codec error. Hmm..

Comment: I'm sorry, are you using Windows? If yes, download ProRes for Win – https://support.apple.com/kb/dl2033?locale=en_US

Comment: H264, MacOS BigSur 11.5.2.

Comment: As I said earlier, you have to use Apple ProRes 422 or Apple ProRes 4444, instead of `.mp4` and `.h264`. Do you have Final Cut Pro X? With FCPX you can easily convert your video into `.mov` with ProRes codec.

Comment: No, I don't. But I have input videos from the web so now I need to find a way to define codec in my python script. Maybe `ffmpeg` can do it.

Comment: Nope. FFMPEG can't do it.

Comment: Download a free version of Blackmagic DaVinci Resolve 17. Put your video on a timeline and then render this video as QuickTime ProRes. – https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236822/discussion-between-shpindler-and-andy-fedoroff).

Comment: It would be cool if I need this operation only once but I have an app to generate videos and I can't manually switch codecs, I need to do it programmatically.

Comment: And after switching codec to ProRes nuke.render shows a lot of `error decoding audio frame` errors so that the resulted audio is broken.

Comment: The other option is NUKE Studio with its timeline. Maybe it's more convenient than Nuke X? Sorry, I must go...

Comment: Is it possible to use NUKE Studio programmatically separately from GUI like I'm running Nuke Python Interpreter to execute code with `import nuke`?

Comment: Yep. Here's nice dotStudio – https://github.com/antiero/dotStudio

Comment: I found a workaround: After getting nuke output it can be merged with audio channel of base video using ffmpeg.